# Hide VS2010 Navigation Bar At The Top Of The Text Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using an addon called Code Map in Visual Studio 2010 which makes the navigation bar at the top of the text editor redundant. Is there a way to hide it? I tried "Hide Navigation Bar" in the Text Editor options but it doesn't seem to do anything when unchecked. I unchecked at the root just to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option that you mentioned works, but unfortunately not for all languages. I tested it in my VS2010, and when I uncheck the "Navigation Bar" box in All Languages section, then it hides navigation bar in C# files, but not in VB. 
If you look more closely on options for other languages than you will see that checkbox for Navigation Bar is locked in VB, CSS, F# and few other. 
You can check Visual Studio 11 Beta, maybe it was changed?

EDIT: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/651e378e-7059-49c6-ade5-8e56c9085c12/ - unfortunately here I found similiar answer.